# What is the best practice to encapsulate third-parties non-serializable classes with Java?

Tags: java, serialization, cassandra

I'm trying to compress a "Row" class of DataStax component `(com.datastax.driver.core.Row)`, but got a not-serializable exception

> java.io.NotSerializableException).

By now, I'm workarounding this with a new class mapping field by field, but seems to be quite verbosity...
Would like to hear best practices in situations like that.

Comment: Create a new class `Row` that you make and is serializable.  Transfer the data from the non-serializable class to the serializable one.

Comment: Use [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) (or other lib) to get rid of the tedious and error prone field by field mapping.

Comment: Thanks @markspace and Andrew!
The solution that better suit to me was using a new serializable class `Row` and transferring data.

Comment: It never hurts to ask if there is a "free" or "E-Z" solution, but the whole point of object oriented programming is to make classes that do what you want.  Generally that should be your first solution.